# Activiti Java Delegate over cached bean recive expressions

Tags: java, spring, osgi, activiti, bpmn

I invoke a Bean with a blueprint resolver to my process Engine. Now I want to pass in an Expression. For this I introduced the variable:

```
Expression kindOf;
```

to my JavaDelegate.

Over the Process I set the kindOf value.

When i start my process i earn:

> Error while Calling BPMN: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiIllegalArgumentException: Field definition uses unexisting field 'kindOf' on class Proxyc8eb67de_0a66_4160_9103_9eda4532b939
>   ActivitiIllegalArgumentException: Field definition uses unexisting field 'kindOf' on class Proxyc8eb67de_0a66_4160_9103_9eda4532b939

But there is the field kindOf.

Can anyone help me out?

Cheers

Marcel

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess what is going on here. Could you prepare failing jUnit test?
Here is a template:
https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-unit-test-template

Regards
Martin